# How can I get field labels from submission data?

Tags: 8, webforms

I have created a custom webform handler by extending WebformHandlerBase. And I can get the data from the WebformSubmission. However, I can only get the machine name of the field. I would like to get field label. For instance, I get "fname" machine name as the key, but I want to get "First Name" or what ever label is set in the admin for this webform.

Does anyone know how I might get to that information from a webform submission entity?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you pass `$form`, and `$form_state` into your custom handler function. You can always access your webform field "label" via **$form** variable.

Try **kint()** or **dd()** `$form['elements']` on specific form and go into depth to find your field, then you can easily get `$form['elements']['my_field_name']['#title']` etc.

Comment: Well, I'm not adding a custom submit handler like I would have in D7. I'm talking about when I extend the WebformHandlerBase class. I'm inside that, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to get to the label. I can get to the data and keys, but not the field label.